# Set a default many to many relation in Laravel to pre-populate create form

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5, relation

I my app I have Articles and Users. This is a many to many relationship where an article can have multiple authors.

Usually I set default values like this:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->field = 'default value';
```

And pass this to the form. I'm not sure how to add the current user `Auth::user()` as a default relation though `$article->users()` as the Laravel methods like attach and sync save to the database. I also tried this without success:

```
$article = new Article(['users' => [0 => Auth::user()->id]]);
```

Comment: What about `$article->users()->attach(Auth::user());`?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký attach attempts to save to the pivot table which results in `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'article_id' cannot be null`.

Comment: First, create the Article. Then save it to the database so Laravel knows its id. Then attach current user to it.

Comment: That might need to be the case. The downside of that is would need to bypass validation of required fields & could leave a lot of blank draft articles in the system which seems a bit messy just for pre-populating defaults. Adding this to the form might be easier but still not ideal.